# Java setting system property using command line

Tags: java, command-line, jvm-arguments, system-properties

While reading java `man` page, I found the `-Dproperty=value` flag which stats that by passing this flag, it will create a system property with value = value. 
I wrote a test java code:

```
class File{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("HOLA");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("blah"));
    }
}
```

I compiled the same with `javac File.java` and then ran with with command `java File -Dblah=blah` but I got the following output

```
HOLA
null
```

and then I ran with as `java -Dblah=blah File` and then I got the expected output:

```
HOLA
blah
```

The question is: Is this a bug or is this an intentional behavior. It does seem a bug because in most of the program, order doesn't matter at command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

System properties (and other options like the classpath) need to be passed before program arguments. See the [usage page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

```
java [ options ] class [ arguments ]
```

Answer (score 8):

The `-D` needs to come *before* the class name, because anything *after* the class name is regarded as an argument to the Java app itself... and the Java app may choose to do anything it likes with `-D`, or any other JVM options.

Basically, the syntax is:

```
java [jvm-args] class-name [application-args]
```